# Why am I getting a ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created a virtual environment in VS Code, to use Python 3.8.10

I have activated the environment by running the activate script.

I have used **pip3 install** to install my modules (pandas and requests)

I have confirmed their presence by looking in the directory **venv\Lib** and can see them

I have also confirmed their presence by running **pip freeze > requirements.txt**

However when I run my python file that has an **import requests** or **import pandas** I get a ModuleNotFoundError

Can anyone assist me with this

Comment: Are you running your code form VS Code to use that particular environment or are you running it in OS?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `Python: Default Interpreter Path` setting set in vscode to a different interpreter?

If you run `python file_name.py` from the same terminal that you run `pip freeze` does it also give the error? That's a sign something in VSCode is configured to another interpreter.

Comment: The above test has been useful. When I use "python file_name.py" from this same terminal (powershell) it works and finds the module.  The problem occurs when I press the "run python file" button in the top right, of VS Code.  When I do this a new terminal (python) opens and my environment is no longer active in it and the module cant be found. Again, if i activate the venv in this terminal and run the "python file_name.py" it succeeds but if I press the "run python file" button it fails.  Is anyone able to advise why this could be?

Comment: That means it's installed to another interpreter. Check your PATH environment variable, or set the path in VSCode. See [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) or the other answer.

Comment: Ah I think I see now...I think the "run python file" must use the global interpreter whereas from the terminal uses the environment....I had assumed the button should also use the environment version but perhaps not.